# Why did Rolls Royce use an inverter in their electric aircraft though they are using axial flux DC motors?

Tags: inverter

An inverter converts DC power into AC power.  Why did Rolls Royce use an inverter even though battery provides DC power only - exactly what they actually need for the axial flux motor.

Comment: Whether axial or radial flux, brushless motors with a wound stator and permanent magnet rotor (whether BLDC or permanent magnet synchronous motor) require variable frequency drive to run. So they are always powered by some form of inverter. It is unfortunate and confusing that these motors are referred to as DC motors. But do take note that these motors also cannot be powered directly by AC power from mains. Induction motors typically are designed so that they can be started and run directly from AC mains power.

Comment: So please clarify that the axial flux motor uses AC or DC?

Comment: Three-phase alternating current. However, the alternating current must be supplied by a suitable variable frequency drive or inverter. You cannot power a permanent magnet brush-less motor of any type directly from 50 Hz or 60 Hz mains power.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you count solenoids, DC motors don't exist.

Every type of "DC" motor uses an inverter or some sort of commutator to transform the DC power supply into AC. If the motor is "DC brushed", the inverter is simply the brushes and commutator, which steer power supply current through the various windings with appropriate polarity at the appropriate time.

If the coils are on the stator and the rotor has permanent magnets or DC field coils, then the stator coils need to create a rotating magnetic field to make the rotor turn.

If the coils are on the rotor, then they need to create a magnetic field at the correct angle relative to the fixed field of the stator permanent magnets (or field coil). So the field created by the coils doesn't rotate, but the coils themselves rotate, so to keep their field at the proper angle relative to the stator, current must be applied to coils in a round robin fashion in the opposite direction.

So you either need AC, or switching between coils.

To keep turning, the inverter (or brushes) in a DC motor must switch to the next coil in the sequence. So the motor itself is powered by DC, but every coil is powered by AC from the inverter or brushes.

"Brushless DC" motors (including axial flux) replace brushes with electronic inverters. They're really three phase synchronous machines with permanent magnets. The electronic inverter is much smarter than a bunch of mechanical contacts, so it can use specific control algorithms and signal shape to optimize efficiency, power and torque. But it won't work without an inverter.

"DC motor" is just a convenient way to refer to a motor that uses a DC power supply. The inverter/commutator/whatever does the switching must be there for it to work, so it is usually not mentioned. It's like talking about a diesel car: you don't need to mention it has an engine to turn that diesel into work.

But then the manufacturers of "DC brushless motors" will also sell them without the controller, which adds to the confusion, because what they're really selling is three phase permanent magnet synchronous motors. But you can't sell it under that name, because no-one will google that.

Comment: linear motors can use DC, e.g. railguns. but for rotary machines, you are probably right.

Comment: But the motor they are using is provided by YASA (a British company) and its specifications indicate that it is a DC motor.

Comment: @AnkitKumarVishwakarma That's marketing speak. It's extremely doubtful they would market a brushed DC motor for aerospace applications.

Comment: @bobflux: In a brushed DC motor, the commutator does not create a rotating magnetic field. It allows the rotor field to remain somewhat stationary in the turning rotor to maintain a somewhat fixed quadrature alignment with the stationary stator field. A commutator motor is essentially a stationary-field motor while other types of motors are essentially rotating-field motors.

Comment: A unipolar motor is a pure DC motor; it's just pretty useless.

Comment: @Hearth you could argue the contact on the edge is like a brushed commutator with an infinite number of poles ;) besides, DC is flowing in a fixed place on the disk only if it does not turn, otherwise each angular slice of the disk will have current going up and down as it rotates... It never changes sign, but it's really not constant DC...